# how to force ejb3 to reload value from data base and not use those of the context

Tags: jpa, jakarta-ee, ejb-3.0, java-ee-6

Hello here I have a big problem that I hope to find help
here I have two entities

`@Entity`

@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)

@DiscriminatorColumn(name="Role", discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.STRING)
public class Utilisateur implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

```
@Id

@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)

@Column(name="id")
private Long id;
@Column(name="nom",nullable=false)
private String nom;


@Column(name="Role",nullable=false, insertable=false)
private String Role ;
```

//...
}

```
@Entity
```

@Table(name="ResCom")
@DiscriminatorValue("ResCom")
public class ResCom extends Utilisateur {

/...

}

the first thing I do

```
ResCom rsCom= new ResCom(nom,prenom, email,civilite,
                     SysQl.crypePasse(pass));
 gr.create(rsCom);
```

I check my database I see that property is ResCom insert

but when I check the value of role I get null

```
 Utilisateur tets= gr.findByEmail(email);

    message=tets.getEmail()+" and Role :"+tets.getRole()+"";
```

but in my bass it ResCom !!!!!

[image]

the problem disappears when I deploy the project again

I hope you have a solution

And thank you in advance

sorry for my English

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without seeing how you persist, load your entity, i recommend using entity manager's refresh method. Something like,

```
entityManager.refresh(yourEntity);
```

Comment: Thank you very match  now whith     em.clear();

            Object t= (Object) em.createNamedQuery("Utilisateur.findByEmail").setParameter("email", email).getSingleResult();
            
            em.refresh(t); now it work the problme that in the fisrt time i juste add em.refresh( )    ;     thank you again